# Sending photo with vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I am using [ElementUi uploader](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload) and i need to send my file with the rest of my form data, but it doesn't seem to send right details of photo to back-end:

### Screenshots

`Console log when i select an image`

[image: one]

`Data that sent to back-end`

[image: two]

### Code

`photo input`

```
<el-upload
    action="#"
    :limit="1"
    :multiple="false"
    :on-change="photoChanged"
    :on-exceed="handleExceed"
    list-type="picture-card"
    :on-remove="handleRemove"
    :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview"
    :before-remove="beforeRemove"
    :auto-upload="false">
    <i slot="default" class="el-icon-plus"></i>
</el-upload>
<el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible">
    <img width="100%" :src="dialogImageUrl" alt="">
</el-dialog>
```

`Script`

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialogImageUrl: '',
            dialogVisible: false,
            form: {
                name: '',
                slug: '',
                price: '',
                new_price: '',
                sku: '',
                qty: 1,
                active: '',
                photo: '',
                shortDesc: '',
                longDesc: '',
                region: '',
                date1: '',
                date2: '',
                type: [],
                tags: [],
                brand_id: '',
                categories: [],
                resource: '',
                user_id: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(e) { //send data to back-end
            e.preventDefault();
            axios.post('/api/admin/products/store', this.form)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
        handleRemove(file) {
            this.form.photo = ''; // remove photo from from when it's removed
        },
        photoChanged(file, fileList){
            this.form.photo = file.raw;  // add photo to form when it's selected
            console.log('file', file) // screenshot 1
            console.log('raw', file.raw) //screenshot 2
        },
        handlePictureCardPreview(file) {
            this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;
            this.dialogVisible = true;
        },
        handleExceed(files, fileList) {
            this.$message.warning(`The limit is 1, you selected ${files.length} files this time, add up to ${files.length + fileList.length} totally, remove old image and try again.`);
        },
        beforeRemove(file) {
            return this.$confirm(`Cancel the transfert of ${ file.name } ?`);
        }
    },
  }
</script>
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: convert your file to base64 then that's it.

Comment: @Qonvex620 how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Well I have decided to give up on sending image with rest of data to backend and upload image first with `action="#"` in my input and in return i get file name in my form and just send the file name with rest of form instead of sending image file.

```
<el-upload
  action="/api/upload"
  :on-success="handleAvatarSuccess"
.....>


methods: {
  handleAvatarSuccess(res, file) {
    this.form.photo = res.data;
  },
}
```

So it sends my file to back-end as soon as it's selected and set the name of stored file in my `form.photo` and that name will be send with rest of my form inputs.

Hope it could be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

convert your file to base64

when you select an image, use code below

```
       onImageChange() {
          let file = this.form.photo

          if (file == '')
                return;

           this.createImage(file);
       }

       createImage(file) {
           let reader = new FileReader();
           let el = this
           reader.onload = (e) => {
                el.form.photo = e.target.files[0];      
           };
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       },
```

attach onImageChange function in your input file

Comment: when i select file it returns `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."`

Comment: still `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."`

Comment: how do you pass file in onImageChange function ?, maybe your not passing a file

Comment: basically i only user your `createImage` function and change the name to `photoChanged` as my `photoChanged` is on change method `:on-change="photoChanged"` so the file is definitely  exist but some how we're unable to read it with `fileReader()`

Comment: `photoChanged(file) {
           let reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.form.photo = e.target.files[0];      
           };
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },`

Comment: in your input file , how do you attach it it ? I assumed you used v-model on it and use it as a fine on that function

Comment: OK there wasn't any `v-model="form.photo"` i add one but result is the same

Comment: ok now doesn't return error but sends photo as empty to back-end `photo: ""`

Comment: still sends empty :/

Comment: i've tried this `reader.onload = (e) => {
                console.log('e', e)` but nothing prints in console. some how process won't reach to that point

Comment: can you show the console log of this.form.photo upon onChange  ?

Comment: with this `photoChanged(ee) {
            console.log(ee)
            let file = this.form.photo
            if (file == '')
                return;
            this.createImage(file);
            console.log(this.form.photo)
        },` i get `ee` in console which is same as my first screenshot, but nothing prints about `form.photo` maybe that `if` statement doing something wrong\

Comment: just remove first the condition to check what's the value of your form.photo upon onChange

Answer (score 1):

I have used FormData to send the photo or document to the server.
[JavaScript FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

```
  <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" v-model="imageData.name">
      </div>
     <div>
        <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc" v-model="imageData.account">
      </div>
    <label for="userfile">Upload file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>

export default {
    data() {
        return { 
            imageData: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        uploadImageToServer() {
            // 1.Save the form Data and return the new id to save the image 
            axios.post('/api/admin/products/store', this.imageData)
            .then(res => {
                if(res.id) {
                //2. Save the image to id
                let formData = new FormData();
                let file = document.getElementById('userfile');
                formData.append('file', file)
                axios.post('/api/admin/products/image/{id}', formData)
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res)
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            }) 

        }
    }
}
```

Here,
Both form data & file data maynot be send in single requst.
1. Saving the form data and return the id.
2. Saving the image data to the id.
Replace the html with 'element-ui' syntax. Ensure that your rest api receives the form data as the input.

Comment: yes but the problem with this is the way `el-upload>` tag process the image data otherwise it wouldn't be the issue and formData would work just fine.